Getting "Missing Command Parameter" from winappdriver
When we trying to switch the window handle from winappdriver,
driver.swith_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])

We got the below error,
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\user_name\PycharmProjects\my_automation\test_ui,py", line 60, in test_login
    self.driver.switch_to.window(self.driver.window_handles[o])
File "C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\automation\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\switch_to.py", line 130, in window
    self._w3c_window(window_name)
File "C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\automation\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\switch_to.py", line 138, in  _w3c_window
    send_handle(window_name)
File "C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\automation\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\switch_to.py", line 134, in send_handle
    self._driver.execute(Command.SWITCH_TO_WINDOW, {"handle": h})
File "C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\automation\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 440 in execute
    self.error_handLer.check_response(response)
File "C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\automation\Lib\site-packages\appium\webdriver\errorhandLer.py", line 30, in check_response
    raise wde
Fle "C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\automation\Lib\site-packages\appium\webdriver\errorhandler.py", line 26 in check_response
    super().check_response(response)
File "C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\automation\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\enote\errorhandler.py" line 245 in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Missing Command Parameter: name


always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

edited my question and mentioned the error with full stack trace.

error shows .window_handles[o] with char o instead of number 0 - maybe this makes problem

Maybe first use print() (and print(type(...)), print(len(...)), etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called "print debugging" and it helps to see what code is really doing.
